# How can I setup a project Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 to read barcode

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I need to know how to implement a barcode reader. Had implemented a previously but update the version of the project for Silverlight 8.1 (previously used version 8). Does anyone have an example?

I'm looking for several tutorials on how to read barcode (scan) for windows phone, but yet have not found one that supports version 8.1 SILVERLIGHT

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking... elaborate quickly else your question will be closed.

Comment: @PaulZahra I'm looking for several tutorials on how to read barcode (scan) for windows phone, but yet have not found one that supports version 8.1 SILVERLIGHT

Comment: And SO specifically states that it's purpose is NOT to recommend books, tutorials, etc.

Comment: @LuizNegrini Have you tried https://barcodescannerwp8.codeplex.com/ ? Found searching on google for 'silverlight 8.1 barcode scanner'

Comment: @PaulZahra I've tried this. Now I'm trying to implement this: https://zxingnet.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Clients/SimpleWindowsPhone8Demo/MainPage.xaml.cs but this line "_photoCamera.Initialized += _photoCamera_Initialized;" but the focus on the camera is not running.

Comment: @LuizNegrini Shouldn't that be _photoCamera.Initialized += OnPhotoCameraInitialized; ?